# Posting a question that was solved before being post.

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I wanted to submit a question on MSE, but just as I was about to click the <kbd>Post Your Question</kbd> button, I realized I could solve that problem in a way I had never thought of before. That question is a standard textbook teaching material but I decided not to refer to the given proof. Is it OK to go ahead and submit the question? And what about the answer I just thought of which is nearly the same as the textbook proof, is it OK to post it?

#### Concerns

1. I wonder if there are other elegant ways to solve that problem.
2. Is adding unique questions to MSE OK, even if I knew the answer right before I clicked the button?

Comment: You can even post question at answer at the same time: [Recently rolled out SE Encyclopedia feature.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4286/recently-rolled-out-se-encyclopedia-feature)

Comment: @MartinSleziiak Yes, I figured that out. It makes me feel better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've seen several questions of the form: "here is a problem. Here is how I solved it. Is there any other (simpler) way to solve it? Is there a proof that doesn't use theorem X? or only uses theorem Y?"

I personally like these kinds of questions because I get to learn something out of it.

Oh, I should add; there are related tags to check out: [proof-strategy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-strategy), [proof-writing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-writing), and [alternative-proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternative-proof).

Comment: (+1) Thank you, it's a good advice. I like to read solved questions a lot because I can occasionally discover a whole continent of interesting stuffs I didn't know. I can benefit from [tag:proof-writing]. I will reword that question.

Answer (score 3):

If I were to do that, I would probably ask the question as normal, put my own answer as a community-wiki answer, and make a note in the question that I had solved it and posted my answer below, but I am now interested in other possible solutions (and would like verification that my solution is actually correct).

Comment: (+1) I'd still like to know under what circumstances am I expected/permitted to accept my own CW answer, i.e. that if other answerers are helpful to me, I should not accept my CW answer, etc.? Thanks, I'd like to know the norm on MSE.

Comment: @FrenzYDT. These sorts of questions [have](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1839/questions-whose-answers-are-known-to-the-op) [been](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1401/what-to-do-if-you-figure-out-the-answer-to-your-own-question) [asked](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2244/answering-own-question-ahead-of-time) [before](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2637/policy-on-accepting-my-own-answer), so you may get an idea of the site's policy from those answers.

Comment: A question should be *self-contained*. In this case, a specific proof is actually a *part* of the question. Hence it should be supplied *in the question statement*, not down in the answers.

Comment: I don't see why the answer should be CW.